# Pass a Class (UILabel) with its properties through a function Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift, uilabel

I am wondering if anyone knows how to (if possible) pass a UILabel through a function while being able to access and change its properties? Here's what I have:

```
func plusMinusChange(minus: UILabel, plus: UILabel) {
    if (minus.hidden) {
        minus.hidden=false
        plus.hidden=true
    } else {
        minus.hidden=true
        plus.hidden=false
    }
}
```

And here's how I am calling it:

```
plusMinusChange(firstMinus, firstPlus)
```

I know this is probably really illogical but I want to give it a try anyways. If you were wondering, firstMinus and firstPlus are linked to UILabels on the storyboard.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong here. What problem are you having?

Comment: In the call statement, I get the error, "Missing argument label 'plus:' in call"  When I let it fix it it changes the call to plusMinusChange(firstMinus, plus: firstPlus) and that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: thats correct if you don't want to add the plus: you have to declare the function with an underscore before "plus" like this: "fun plusMinusChange(minus: UILabel, _ plus: UILabel) {"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to methods (that is, `func`s defined within a class or other type) require parameter labels for the second (and subsequent) parameter but not the first. If you want to change which labels are required at the call site, you change the declaration.

To require a label on the first parameter:

```
func plusMinusChange(#minus: UILabel, plus: UILabel) {
```

To require no label on the second:

```
func plusMinusChange(minus: UILabel, _ plus: UILabel) {
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Do you know the reason for requiring to have the parameter label on the second one if you don't change the declaration?

Comment: It has to with Cocoa method naming conventions: Cocoa API calls like to read like sentences, so we have method names like `doSomethingWithThis(a, andThat: b)`. Labels make it easier to keep track of parameters, too: imagine a method call with 15 parameters and trying to remember which is which by position alone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a conditional if there. You can use ! in front of the property to toggle its value as follow:

```
minus.hidden = !minus.hidden
plus.hidden =  !plus.hidden
```

Comment: So instead of that whole if statement I would just use those two lines?